# Arithmetic Operation with Case when statement in PHP (codeigniter)

Tags: php, codeigniter, math

I want to update `DURASI_KENDALA` column with some condition. This is my code on model.php

```
public function durasikendala() {
        $str = "UPDATE dbhpl.pelayanan SET pelayanan.DURASI_KENDALA = "
                . "CASE WHEN pelayanan.ID_KENDALA == 1 OR pelayanan.ID_KENDALA == 2 OR "
                . " pelayanan.ID_KENDALA == 6 OR pelayanan.ID_KENDALA == 7"
                . " THEN pelayanan.ESTIMASI "
                . " WHEN pelayanan.ID_KENDALA == 3 OR pelayanan.ID_KENDALA == 4 OR "
                . " pelayanan.ID_KENDALA == 8 OR pelayanan.ID_KENDALA == 9"
                . " THEN pelayanan.LAMA "
                . " WHEN pelayanan.ID_KENDALA == 5 THEN (pelayanan.LAMA - pelayanan.HARI_LIBUR) END";
        $this->db->query($str);
        if ($this->db->affected_rows() > 0) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

But, the code can`t run because operation aritmetic on:

```
WHEN pelayanan.ID_KENDALA == 5 THEN (pelayanan.LAMA - pelayanan.HARI_LIBUR)
```

The condition is 
If ID_KENDALA = 5 then DURASI_KENDALA = LAMA - HARI_LIBUR

The data type already same in int.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: What is `==` supposed to do?  It is not a MySQL operator, to the best of my knowledge.

Comment: as @GordonLinoff suggest remove `==` and edit with single `=` and try once